# How to display user image in Navigation Bar that is part of master page in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-views

I want to display user's image in menu bar that is part of master page. 
master.blade.php

```
<div class="login_area">
    @if (Auth::check())
    <img src="{{asset('public/user_images/1531068734.jpg')}}" height="40px"
    width="40px" alt="" class="pull-left img-circle login"> 
    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();                                                
      document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  </form>

     @else 
     <a href="http://www.abc.in\login">Login</a><a href="http://abc.in/register">Registration</a> 
@endif
   </div>
```

Image model : Each image is associated with each profile. and each profile is associated with user.

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class image extends Model
{

protected $fillable = 
['profile_id','user_id','image_name','image_status','image_permission'];
protected $primaryKey = 'image_id';
public function profile()
{

return $this->belongsTo(profile::class,'id','id');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the general method to display an image as below. You do not need to use `public/` as it is the default path for assets.

```
<img src="/user_images/1531068734.jpg" height="40px" width="40px" alt="" class="pull-left img-circle login">
```

Comment: my question is how to pass image url from controller to master page view. because there is no route for master page.

Comment: You can simply get the profile image from the `Auth::user()`, i suppose you have the relationship between user and profile image

Answer (score 0):

Symply using

```
<img src="{{ auth()->user()->image }}" height="40px" 
     width="40px" alt="" class="pull-left img-circle login" />
```

Comment: how can i do it using query building ? because a user has many images, i need to display only profile picture

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `View` class's `share` method to make a variable (or any value) available to all views in laravel.

> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the  AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house them

Inside the AppServiceProvider file, you will add the code like this:
`View::share('key', 'value')`
For example:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Replace 'key' with what you like, and 'value' with the user image path.

Solution 2:
You can also use ViewComposer for this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

You do not need pass image url to view from controller. You can print image path in view.

I saw an error your src value of  tag. You are using as

> asset('public/user_images/1531068734.jpg')

but asset method are using already "public" as root folder. You should remove "public" so, it should be following to;

> // If image path stored as only file name;
>
> asset('user_images/' . auth()->user()->needed_profile_image_column)
>
> // If image path stored as full path with file name;
>
> asset(auth()->user()->needed_profile_image_column)

Could you try what I mentioned above?

Comment: each user has multiple images, i need to display only profile image( image_status == 'profile') . how to use where condition with this relationship.auth()->user()->needed_profile_image_column

Comment: You can custom attribute in your model. You can set any image to this custom attribute. Check the laravel model attribute on laravel doc.

Comment: i want to display only profile image uploaded by that user. like we see in facebook navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

I want describe more detail my above comment. 
Laravel provide adding a custom attribute that for using as db table column.

Please add following code to your User model;

```
.....

protected $appends = [
    'profile_photo',
];

/**
 * Get user profile photo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProfilePhotoAttribute()
{
    $profile_photo = null;
    if($this->image_status == 'profile'){
        $profile_photo = public_path('user_images/' . $this->image));
    }
    return $profile_photo;
}
```

Please add following code to your navigation area;

```
<div class="login_area">
    @if (Auth::check())
        <img src="{{ auth()->user()->profile_photo }}" height="40px" width="40px" alt="" class="pull-left img-circle login"> 
        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
    @else 
        <a href="http://www.abc.in\login">Login</a>
        <a href="http://abc.in/register">Registration</a> 
    @endif
</div>
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: i tried but did not work. now i have updated my image model. please check it

Comment: {{ auth()->user()->profile()->image()->profile_photo }}